# Scrapy CSS selector to select one of multiple similar types tags

Tags: python, css, scrapy

I would like to know to select data from a specific tags structure out of multiple similar tags structure. For example, consider below structures. Now i would like to only select data out of first "vcol" so that i can read ITEM1, ITEM2, ITEM3, ITEM4.

```
<div class="main">

    <div class="vcol">
        <div class="cls">
            <ul class="ul_style">
                <li class="li_style"> <h3 class="item"> ITEM1 </h3></li>
                <li class="li_style"> <h3 class="item"> ITEM2 </h3></li>
                <li class="li_style"> <h3 class="item"> ITEM3 </h3></li>
                <li class="li_style"> <h3 class="item"> ITEM4 </h3></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="vcol">
        <div class="cls">
            <ul class="ul_style">
                <li class="li_style"> <h3 class="item"> ITEM5 </h3></li>
                <li class="li_style"> <h3 class="item"> ITEM6 </h3></li>
                <li class="li_style"> <h3 class="item"> ITEM7 </h3></li>
                <li class="li_style"> <h3 class="item"> ITEM8 </h3></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="vcol">
        <div class="cls">
            <ul class="ul_style">
                <li class="li_style"> <h3 class="item"> ITEM9 </h3></li>
                <li class="li_style"> <h3 class="item"> ITEM10 </h3></li>
                <li class="li_style"> <h3 class="item"> ITEM11 </h3></li>
                <li class="li_style"> <h3 class="item"> ITEM12 </h3></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

If i write scrapy code as below, i am getting all ITEMS1 - 12.

```
for item in response.css('.vcol .cls .ul_style li'):
    item.css('h2 ::text').extract_first()
```

Any suggestion, how to get only ITEM1-4 ?

Tried to loop through different classes, however i am always getting all items

Comment: what about `.vcol:nth-child(1) li`? By the way, why a second selection with `h2` but the HTML contains `<h3>` tags?

Comment: Thanks @PatrickJanser thats worked for. I was not aware about nth-child / first-child.  Appreciate your quick feedback. Any that was mistake. It should be h3, not h2. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned in my comments, you can use the
[:nth-child() CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)
to only match the first `<div class="vcol">`.

Then, I don't think it's worth doing two CSS queries as you effectively have
one single **ITEM*** per `<li>`. So you could use `.vcol:nth-child(1) h3` or `.vcol:nth-child(1) .item` to select the HTML tags you want to extract.